# Uploading image to folder named by id of django object using api

Tags: django

I want uploaded files to be placed in folder named the id of an object.

When I was doing sites by only using Django I did it like this:

```
I want uploaded files to be placed in folder named the id of an object.

When I was doing sites by only using Django I did it like this:

def getImageURL(instance, filename):
    path = os.path.join("posts/{}/post_image.png".format(instance.id))
    
    if os.path.isfile("media/" + path):
        print("image with this id already exist, ")
        os.remove("media/posts/{}/post_image.png".format(instance.id))
        return path
    else:
        return path
        

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="no title")
    text = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to=getImageURL, blank=True, default="no-image.png")
    posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

It also works when I'm uploading an image using the admin panel. But when I'm doing the exact same thing through api, my images are being uploaded to folder named "None" which leads to overwriting the image after making a new post.

Comment: The `id` of an object is `None` before the object is saved...

Comment: @thebjorn so if I make post without image and then edit it and replace deafult img with mine it will work ?